# Pivot Table With Text Labels

Tags: tableau-crm

I'm looking to create a leaderboard where the names of a numerically ranked column populate the cells of a pivot table in Tableau CRM, but it only allows numerical values to fill in the pivot cells. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are your values cardinal (`1, 2, 3, 4`) or are they ordinal (`1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th` or `First, Second, Third, Fourth`)? Oftentimes for analytics software to treat something as a measure instead of a dimension it just needs to be as a number. You should be able to add that to your dataset relatively easily.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I have three columns currently: Quarter-Year, Location, Rank. I would like to create a pivot where the index/rows are Quarter-Years, columns are Ranks (sorted 1-x), and the entries are the names of the locations. The ranks are cardinal values